# Python 2.7 and TKinter?

Tags: linux, centos, centos5

How do you compile Python/TKinter? I installed tk-devel and then recompiled python which got rid of a warning about tk. But Imaging still says

*** TKINTER support not available

Also when I try /locate tkinter it says

/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-dynload/_tkinter.so

How do I compile tkinter for python 2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got is installed. Apparently it is disabled by default even though every site I was on said it was enabled by default :(